# File function in terraform not detecting files in the path

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

This is my code for lambda role and I want my function to read the file from the file path of iam/lambda-assume-policy.json:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "lambda_role"

  assume_role_policy = file("./iam/lambda-assume-policy.json")
}
```

When i run terraform plan, this is the error it throws:

```
   Call to function "file" failed: no file exists at
   iam/lambda-assume-policy.json.
```

Comment: Is this resource inside a module? If so can you show the directory layout you are using?

Answer (score 5):

By default, the `file` function resolves the given path relative to the current working directory where you ran Terraform. That's commonly the directory containing the root module.

In the common case where a file is included as part of a module, we often want to use a path relative to that module's own directory rather than the root. We can do that by interpolating `path.module`, like this:

```
  assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/iam/lambda-assume-policy.json")
```

In order to allow Terraform configurations to usually be agnostic to the platform where Terraform is being run, Terraform configurations conventionally use forward slashes because they are used by Unix systems and they are *supported* by Windows systems (even though the backslash is the default separator). Therefore `path.module` produces a path containing forward slashes even on Windows. with the expectation that the rest of the path you write after it will also use forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `Terraform Cloud`, you should change the execution mode from `remote` to `local` in your workspace.

How about using the `interpolation` syntax `${file("${path.module}/iam/lambda-assume-policy.json")}`